# how can i get field by field from mongodb and put it into labeledpoint

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, machine-learning, label, decision-tree

I want to create a `LabeledPoint` in Spark using data from mongodb. I can get fields from mongodb to spark by:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db1 = client.newumc
collection1 = db.data_classification
q_2 = collection1.find({}, {'q2':1,'_id':0})
q_1 = collection1.find({}, {'q1':1,'_id':0})
q_38 = collection1.find({}, {'q38':1,'_id':0})
_result = collection.find({},{'qresultat':1,'_id':0})
```

where `q1`, `q2`, `q38` and `qresultat` are the fields from mongodb (`q1`, `q2`, `q38` are the features and `_result` is the label).

But this does not works for me:

```
lbpoint =  LabeledPoint(result, array([q1, q2, q38]))
```

and type(q2) is

```
pymongo.cursor.Cursor
```

Can anyone please help me or if someone already had some code of decision tree with mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by uusing

```
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("myApp") \
.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/newumc.classification_data") \
.config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/newumc.classification_data") \
.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
column1 = df[1]
column2 = df[2]
```